# I want to create a Virtual Relation in Spring Jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am creating an application. In the application we have different Users such as Company, Employee and Customers. Each of them have different information needed to be stored. and each user have (null or one) to (one or many) relations. I have created an `Address` class and `User` class. When I create a relation as shown down below I get a recursion error. How can I overcome this problem? When I deleted the connection between User and Address, I need to access Addresses as well. What do I suppose to do?

Address Class :

```
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
....

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public enum AddressType {
        HOME_ADDRESS,
        WORK_ADDRESS,
        OTHER
    }

}
```

User Class:

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = EAGER)
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = EAGER)
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your relationship. However it is crucial to know **when** you get this exception. I suspect it is due to creating a JSON response for a `User` (or `Address`) or even worse using Lombok with `@Data` on an entity and expecting the `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` to be proper.

Comment: When I am trying to save a user or an address I receive errors. I need to access those information via getters or setters. I am note sure why I am facing this problem.

Comment: How are you managing the relationship? Make sure that you are properly setting the user to the address (and adding it correctly to the collection of addresses). Also make sure you ave a proper equals/hashcode implementation in your code, finally if you get an error show the code which shows the error and the error you get.